# The Devil's or Death's daughter running a bar for supernaturals?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for book (first in a series?), where the daughter of the Devil or Death is running a bar -- I think mostly for supernatural patrons.

I can't be much more specific than that, since I never read more than the first few chapters.

Comment: When did you read this book? Who were the patrons? Was it humorous or serious? Was the bar a main feature of the story (e.g. did the stories revolve around the bar) or was it merely a setting?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be part of the Disworld series by Terry Pratchett? On several occasions one of the main characters, Susan (Not the daughter of Death but someone who occasionally stands in for him) visits a bar called [Biers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankh-Morpork#Notable_locations).

Wikipedia has a pretty good description:

> Biers is a pub frequented by creatures of the night, usually lumped
> together as "undead", though they can include werewolves and bogeymen.
> Difficult to find, unless you happen to be "the right sort." It is
> often compared to Cheers but with the tagline "Where everybody knows
> your shape". **Susan Sto Helit** is a noted frequenter of Biers. The more
> typical clientele occasionally loudly demand to know what she thinks
> she's doing there. They seldom do so twice.
>
> The barman of Biers is
> named Igor, though he doesn't appear to be an Igor. It's best to eye
> what he serves carefully; as Pratchett noted in Hogfather, *"When Igor
> the barman was asked for a Bloody Mary, he didn't mix a metaphor."* At
> some point in the past, the pub was known as The Crown and Axe; a
> nearly-blind old regular, Mrs. Gammage, still frequents the place,
> mistaking the undead staff and clientele for the previous inhabitants,
> none of them having the heart to gainsay her.

Comment: Note that Susan is usually referred to as Death's granddaughter, not just someone who stands in for him.

Comment: The daughter of his adopted daughter.